# How can I use LightStreamer DotNetStandard library in c# project

Tags: c#

My c# project using framework v4.6.1. And I want to download Lightstreamer.DotNetStandard.Client from NuGet. But they said 'This package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with the framework.'. How can I solve it?

Comment: Switch from .Net Framework to .Net Standard?

Comment: I can't understand.Please explain more specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you upgrade the project to target .NET Framework 4.7.2 or higher? Alternatively you can use the [Lightstreamer.DotNet.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lightstreamer.DotNet.Client/) library, which are basically the same API but guarantee compatibility with .Net framework 4.5.